# Basic Loop Issue with Java Code - How do I allow a player to gamble multiple times in the terminal?

Tags: java, loops, terminal, java.util.scanner

I just started learning Java a week or two ago and I wanted to create a silly little gambling software within the terminal; however, the player is only able to gamble once even though I would like them to be able to gamble several times.

Code:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gambler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int balance = 100;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("--> Current Balance: $" + balance + " <--");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter the Java Gambler simulator?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
        System.out.println();
        String yesOrNo;
        yesOrNo = scanner.nextLine();
        if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("[!] Welcome to the Java Gambler! [!]");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The only Java gambling software in all of Java County!");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("If the chosen number is {1}, the player automatically wins $20.");
            System.out.println("If the chosen number is {2}, the player automatically wins $10.");
            System.out.println("If the chosen number is {3}, the player automatically wins $5.");
            System.out.println("All other numbers are an automatic loss.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Continue?");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
            System.out.println();
            String yesOrNo2;
            yesOrNo2 = scanner.nextLine();
            if (yesOrNo2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Gambling Options:");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("[A] $1 Bet (1/20 $20, 1/20 $10, 1/20 $5)");
                System.out.println("[B] $5 Bet (1/10 $20, 1/10 $10, 1/10 $5)");
                System.out.println("[C] $10 Bet (1/5 $20, 1/5 $10, 1/5 $5)");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Gambling Selection: ");
                System.out.println();
                String continueGambling = "Yes";
                while (continueGambling.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    String gamblingSelection;
                    gamblingSelection = scanner.nextLine();
                    String a = "A";
                    String b = "B";
                    String c = "C";
                    if (gamblingSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
                        balance = balance - 1;
                        int aSelection = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("And the number is... " + aSelection);
                        System.out.println();
                        switch (aSelection) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $20!");
                                balance = balance + 20;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $10!");
                                balance = balance + 10;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $5!");
                                balance = balance + 5;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Sorry, no luck this time...");
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (gamblingSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(b)) {
                        balance = balance - 5;
                        int bSelection = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("And the number is... " + bSelection);
                        System.out.println();
                        switch (bSelection) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $20!");
                                balance = balance + 20;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $10!");
                                balance = balance + 10;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("You won $5! Its a free spin, I guess...");
                                balance = balance + 5;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Sorry, no luck this time...");
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (gamblingSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(c)) {
                        balance = balance - 10;
                        int cSelection = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("And the number is... " + cSelection);
                        System.out.println();
                        switch (cSelection) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("Congrats, you have won $20!");
                                balance = balance + 20;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("You won $10! Its a free spin, I guess...");
                                balance = balance + 10;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("You won $5! At least its somethin...");
                                balance = balance + 5;
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Sorry, no luck this time...");
                                System.out.println("--> Your new balance: $" + balance + " <--");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("Continue?");
                                System.out.println();
                                System.out.println("[Yes] [No]");
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                continueGambling = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            else {
                String wrongValue = "Invalid response. Please try again.";
                System.out.println(wrongValue);
            }
        }
        else if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
            System.out.println("You sure are missing out...");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid response. Please try again.");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the FULL code on GitHub: https://github.com/OkBrock/Gambler

I did a loop and made a scanner but every time I type "Yes" nothing happens.

Summary:
I need the player to have the ability to gamble several times with a singular balance.
I have made a loop with a scanner but nothing happens. Check the code to see.

Comment: Have you learned about `while` loops yet? If not: you'll learn this when you get to those. If you have, ask yourself what your repeating vs. halting condition would be if you, the human, played this game with another human.

Comment: Every programmer needs to know how to debug code - both his own code and other people's. This line of your code is outside of the `while` loop: `continueGambling = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: @Abra I have moved the statement continueGambling = scanner.nextLine(); around and nothing happens

Comment: _nothing happens_ means that you are in an infinite loop. I repeat, you need to learn how to debug your code. If you are using an IDE then it should have a debugger. I suggest that you learn how to use it.

Comment: @Abra Alright, my bad

Comment: you had 2 things wrong with the code one abra already mention it the 2nd is you have the 3 options outside of the while loop just put them inside the loop instead of before.Just a quick note you should try and refactor your code there is a lot of repetetive code

Comment: @Anon Ah, I see! I do not know how I missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrockBenton Most likely it was missed because of the large vertical space and deep nesting *(code turned on its side is not a graph of how awesome it is ;)* In other words, mirroring the previous refactoring comment: "chunking up" some of the functionality, like the balance and options output, can be moved into a supporting function. That alone would go a long way towards de-talling the code, which in turn makes it much easier to reason about.

Comment: @DaveNewton Good to know. The code was definitely weirdly long and somewhat confusing, but I guess limiting repetition is a part of the learning process! I will work on that. Thank you.